# Chosen is not styling my select drop-down properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

Here is my code:

```
<link href="Content/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<div>
<select id="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Select an option...">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#chzn-select").chosen();

</script>
```

This is the result:

[image: chosen styling]

I can "select" Option 1 or Option 2, and they will appear where the "Select an option..." label is.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the relative url is correct? href="Content/chosen.css" -- maybe it should be href="/Content/chosen.css"

Comment: Why are loading the plugin twice?

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: @xec, you were right. This was an issue relating to my url for css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code, it working for me.

```
<link href="http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<div>
 <select id="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Select an option...">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option 2</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#chzn-select").chosen();
</script>
```

Here is the [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8WZM/1/) (working demo of your code)

chosen.jquery.js was included twice in your code. Also i think chosse.css path need to be corrected in your code as per your directory structure.